# jQuery selector for uncommon tag ID

Tags: jquery-selectors, html, jquery-1.6

I have this tag ID, pretty uncommon:

```
<select name="/State" id="/State">
```

It seems I cannot use jQuery selector `$('#/State')` to select this object.

I can select it using `$("#\U002FState")`, but I cannot print the `id` attribute:

```
javascript:alert($("#\U002FState").attr('id'))
```

What can I do to correctly select this object?

Comment: Are you certain you can select it with `$("#\U002FState")`? How did you test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `\\` before `/` `$('#\\/State')`

**Additional links:**

jQuery selectors: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

W3C recommendation: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier

Comment: Yes this works to select the object but I cannot read the id attribute?! :-( It seems it can be done with `document.getElementById("/Estado").getAttribute('id')`

Comment: Ok, it was just a mismatch with id "/Estado" and "/State". Now it is working with `$('#\\/State').attr('id')!`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're only supporting `HTML5` browsers, you'll have issues when selecting by ID, because a `/` in an ID is not valid in `HTML4`.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name

> **ID** and **NAME** tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

You could use the [`attribute-equals-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), but performance will degrade:

```
$('select[id="/State"]');
```

Though it's helpful to include the [`element-selector`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/) as I did above.

**Here's a working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/LVEjS/

Answer (score 0):

as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html) `/` is not a valid character in id's, so your tags are not standards compliant and it's better to fix that problem than to work around it.